# Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't wake up from suspend anymore

Tags: 20.04, suspend, power-management

My laptop has recently started to not wake up from suspend. The screen remains blank with only a white dash blinking in the corner. I always have to resort to pressing the power button to turn it off. Sometimes it gets stuck on the booting screen as well. This didn't happen until 2 weeks ago. I tried disabling auto suspend but the same thing happens when I close the lid. Sometimes it wakes up and then upon entering the password, it goes to the blank screen with the dash blinking in the corner.

I'm running Ubuntu on a separate SSD on a laptop that also runs Windows on another SSD, although I think I broke the Windows one while installing Ubuntu some months ago.
I have only just switched to Ubuntu after 15 years of using Mac so I'm not very knowledgeable on things. I loved Ubuntu so much and I'm so sad that it is broken now. Can you help me please?

- ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
- gnome version: 3.36.8
- graphics: NVIDIA Corporation TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q] / Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 630 (CFL GT2)
- processor: Intel® Core™ i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz × 12

Comment: After this happens and you hard power off, then power back up again, can you go back in your syslog and find the logs when it tried to resume as we'll need more to go on than a description. At the point you reboot it, you should see something like `-- Reboot --` in the log.

Comment: I have found the syslog file but there are more than 450 "reboots" on there. I have copied the section most relevant to the time I rebooted this way the last time but it is massive and I don't know how to paste it here as I can type so many characters in these comment boxes.

Comment: Use https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/

Comment: I hope this is will help and I won't take up too much of your time kind stranger. https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/3jF62jSNqD/